# AddEventListener only working with console log inside

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

This is my code:

```
  let [newPaperShortcut, setNewPaperShortcut] = useState(() => () => { });

  useEffect(() => {
    const handleShortcuts = (event: KeyboardEvent) => {
      if (event.keyCode === N_KEY) {
        console.log("THIS IS SOMEHOW IMPORTANT");
        newPaperShortcut();
      }
    };
    window.addEventListener('keydown', handleShortcuts);

    return () => window.removeEventListener('keydown', handleShortcuts);
  }, []);
```

And somewhere in the code i do:

```
  useEffect(() => {
    setNewPaperShortcut(() => () => {
      console.log("RANDOMLY EXECUTED");
    });
  }, []);
```

This code is only "randomly" working. I get the highest probability of this code working when i have a log message in both lambdas, but in like 90% of the cases if i remove the first log statement, it stops working. It starts working again when i put the console log back in.

Then sometimes it completely breaks and not a single event of my application works again.

Can anyone help me here?

EDIT: maybe helpful, i pass the "setNewPaperShortcut" via react context around to a deep component

Comment: I'm not sure how to help with the provided information.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a problem with the code:

useEffect needs the newPaperShortCut dependency in order to execute again when you set the value

```js
useEffect(() => {
  const handleShortcuts = (event: KeyboardEvent) => {
    if (event.keyCode === N_KEY) {
      console.log("THIS IS SOMEHOW IMPORTANT");
      newPaperShortcut();
    }
  };
  window.addEventListener('keydown', handleShortcuts);

  return () => window.removeEventListener('keydown', handleShortcuts);
}, [newPaperShortcut]);
```